# BeginTime time on Jobs that are requeued on slurm

Tags: slurm, preemption

On Slurm I run a low priority job with requeue on preemption and after some minutes I run a high priority job that kills and sends low priority job on queue. When I type squeue on console I see that high priority is R state and low priority job is PD state with a BeginTime( a time that low priority will start again execution when high priority finished).

***I need to know how does slurm compute the BEGINTIME? Does it has any formulas that uses ???***

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The begin time is estimated from the (expected) duration all other queued and running jobs that are due to start before your job according to their priority. It is recalculated as new jobs with higher priority are inserted or when a job finishes earlier than its expected duration.

In my experience jobs start earlier than the begin time shown by slurm, but mileage may vary.